# Implement receiving DTMF signals

Tags: dtmf, voximplant

How do I implement receiving DTMF signals from my customer in Voximplant, for example, if they enter an extention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [handleTones](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/call#handletones) method: when you receive tone signals, the [ToneReceived](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/callevents#tonereceived) event is fired, and you can obtain the entered digit from the event object.